# elementnotvisibleexception for dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having following problem. I have a table which contains a dropdown in each row corresponsing to first column element of that particular row. But when i try to select an element from a particular dropdown, i am getting element not visible exception.
Here is the page structure :-

```
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:grabPopup::content" style="top:auto;right:auto;left:auto;bottom:auto;width:auto;height:auto;position:relative;">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:grabDialog" class="x1c9">
<div class="x1dh" data-afr-panelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"/>
<div class="x1dh" data-afr-panelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"/>
<div class="x1dh" data-afr-panelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"/>
<div class="x1dh" data-afr-panelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"/>
<table class="x1cg" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" data-afr-shaddec="sd$1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:grabDialog::_cse" class="p_AFResizable x1ct"/>
<td id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:grabDialog::contentContainer" class="p_AFResizable x1o" tabindex="-1">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:grabDialog::_ccntr" class="x1cr" style="width:800px;height:450px;position:relative;overflow:auto;">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:grabpgl1" class="x1a">
<div>
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:pgl108" class="x1a" style="margin-left:15px; width:auto;min-height:500px;/*width:750px;height:500px*/">
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:psl2" class="xpq" style="margin-left:15px; width:auto;min-height:450px; /*width:720px;height:450px*/">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:psl2::f" class="xrd" style="left:0px;top:0px;height:181px;right:0px;padding:0px;border-width:0px">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:pglks4" class="x1a" style="position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px">
<div>
<table id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:j_id__ctru13pc10" class="xsk x1a" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:pb78" class="xsk xdn" style="height:165px">
<table class="xu2 p_AFCore p_AFDefault" border="0" width="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="">
<div class="x1fp p_AFCore p_AFDefault">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:pb78::content" class="x5s p_AFCore p_AFDefault">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:changesTable" class="xsk xsw" _leafcolclientids="['dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:changesTable:j_id__ctru16pc10','dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:changesTable:j_id__ctru18pc10','dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:changesTable:j_id__ctru21pc10']" style="height:114px" tabindex="0">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:changesTable::ch" class="x143" _afrcolcount="3" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 441px; border-right-width: 0px;">
<div id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:changesTable::db" class="x13v" _afrcolcount="3" style="position: relative; width: 441px; overflow: hidden; height: 85px; z-index: 1;">
<table class="x13w x14n" cellspacing="0" _startrow="0" _rowcount="10" _selstate="{'3':true,'2':true,'1':true,'0':true,'7':true,'6':true,'5':true,'4':true,'9':true,'8':true,'afrSelectAll':true}" _totalwidth="363" style="table-layout: fixed; position: relative; width: 441px;">
<tbody>
<tr class="x13u " _afrrk="0">
<tr class="p_AFFocused p_AFSelected x13u " _afrrk="1">
<td class="x14j" align="center" nowrap="" style="">
<td class="x14j" align="center" nowrap="">
<span id="dc1:j_id__ctru2pc2:j_id__ctru10pc2:r1:0:grdeccomp:GAFComp:changesTable:1:j_id__ctru19pc10" class="p_AFFocusTarget p_AFHoverTarget x1z">
```

The last dropdown is the is the item from where i am trying to select an option but getting this exception .
And below is the code that i used to find it.

```
WebElement we = driver.waitVisible(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'changesTable::db')]/table//span[.='" + currentActivity + "']"));
scrollIntoView(we);
Select select = new     Select(driver.waitVisible(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'changesTable::db')]/table//span[.='" + currentActivity + "']/../..//select")));
 select.selectByVisibleText(newActivity);
```

Comment: Could you share the full html for the page?

Comment: I can't find any `select` node in the code you pasted. And could you try to explain your xpath so we could see if we understand correctly.